# Laplace transform of multiplication of two terms

Tags: laplace-transform

I have the following expression to get its laplace transfer:
$$e^{2t}(3t-3t^2)$$

Is it ok to just calculate the transfer of each term then multiply the result? I calculated the expression above like this but it is different than the answer in my book:

$${\frac{1}{s-2}}*\frac{3}{s^2}-\frac{6}{s^3}$$
$$\frac{1}{s-2}*\frac{3s^3-6s^2}{s^5}$$
$$\frac{3s^3-6s^2}{(s-2)s^5}$$

Comment: The Laplace transform of $e^{at}f(t)$ is $F(s-a)$, where $F(s)={\cal L}\{f(t)\}$.

Comment: sorry but what does that mean?

Comment: In general, the Laplace transform of a product is (a kind of) *convolution* of the transform of the individual factors. (When one factor is an exponential, use the shift rule David gave you)

Comment: @Sean87 Find the transform of $3t-3t^2$, then replace "$s$" by "$s-2$".

Comment: To answer your question: No, you cannot just multiply the Laplace transforms together.

Comment: Aaaa I got the idea, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$e^{2t}(3t-3t^2)=3e^{2t}(t-t^2)$$

$$\mathcal{L}(t-t^2)=\mathcal{L}(t)-\mathcal{L}(t^2)=\frac{1}{s^2}-\frac{2}{s^3}$$

You cannot simply multiply the transforms as you wanted (try it on $t^2=t *t$ as a counter example).  However, using David Mitra's shift rule, we have

$$3\mathcal{L}(e^{2t}(t-t^2))=3\left(\frac{1}{(s-2)^2}-\frac{2}{(s-2)^3}\right)=\frac{3(s-4)}{(s-2)^3}$$